# Object property check and format date

Tags: javascript, object

Check header Object type check if type == date then for that property only need to add date format.
find type in headers object incase header object type is date then return final results would be format date

headers object:

```
let headers = [
  {
    key_name: 'trans_id',
    header_value: 'Transaction ID' ,type:'number' 
  },
  {
    key_name: 'start_date',
    header_value: 'Start Date' ,type:'date' 
  }
]
```

results Object:

```
let results = [
  {
    trans_id: '2019124453159',
    start_date:'2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    code: '$'
  },
  {
    trans_id: '2019120534555',
    start_date:'2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    code: 'INR'
  }
]
```

Header type check and format the date.
expected results is:

```
let results = [
  {
    Transaction ID: '2019124453159',
    Start Date : '2021-12-27'
  },
  {
    Transaction ID: '2019120534555',
    Start Date : '2021-12-27'

  }
]
```

I tried with below script its returning without date formatted:

```js
let headers = [{
    key_name: 'trans_id',
    header_value: 'Transaction ID',
    type: 'number'
  },
  {
    key_name: 'start_date',
    header_value: 'Start Date',
    type: 'date'
  }
]

let results = [{
    trans_id: '2019124453159',
    start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    code: '$'
  },
  {
    trans_id: '2019120534555',
    start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    code: 'INR'
  }
]

const mappedHeaders = results.map((r) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(r);
  let newObj = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    const newHeader = headers.find((h) => h.key_name === key);
    if (newHeader) newObj[newHeader.header_value] = r[key];
  }
  return newObj;
});
console.log(mappedHeaders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added an if - is that what you needed?

```js
let headers = [
  { key_name: 'trans_id',   header_value: 'Transaction ID', type: 'number' },
  { key_name: 'start_date', header_value: 'Start Date',     type: 'date' }
]

let results = [{ trans_id: '2019124453159', start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z', code: '$' }, { trans_id: '2019120534555', start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z', code: 'INR' } ];

const mappedHeaders = results.map((r) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(r);
  return  keys.reduce((acc,key) => { 
    const newHeader = headers.find((h) => h.key_name === key);
    if (newHeader) {
      let val = r[key]; 
      if (newHeader.type === 'number') val = parseInt(r[key]);
      else if (newHeader.type === 'date') val = val.split("T")[0];
      acc[newHeader.header_value] = val
    }  
    return acc;
  },{})
});
console.log(mappedHeaders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I want check header type == date then for that property only need to add date format. I added two property only while run time header type and results data would be more so Need to update based on header type check

Answer (score 1):

You have not handled the type of the header. Check whether the type  of the header is a date, if then format it using `moment` and use as the vale, or else just use the value as it is.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let headers = [
  {key_name: 'trans_id',header_value: 'Transaction ID',type: 'number'},
  {key_name: 'start_date',header_value: 'Start Date',type: 'date'}
]

let results = [
  {trans_id: '2019124453159',start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',code: '$'},
  {trans_id: '2019120534555',start_date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',code: 'INR'}
]
const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

const mappedHeaders = results.map((r) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(r);
  let newObj = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    const newHeader = headers.find((h) => h.key_name === key);
    if (newHeader) newObj[newHeader.header_value] = newHeader.type === 'date' ? moment(new Date(r[key])).format(dateFormat) : r[key];
  }
  return newObj;
});
console.log(mappedHeaders)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```